# Program crashes when changing status bar text from thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, winapi

I'm using Qt for interface and winAPI for threading and to index all files on all hard drives. I have a status bar that is QLabel to show which directory currently indexing. To change QLabel text I pass pointer to it as a parameter to function that runs in thread. Program crashes when it changes QLabel text, but if run it without changing QLabel text it executes propely. Debugger stops at the last row of following

```
     Function: ntdll!RtlpSetUserPreferredUILanguages
0x77d656a9  <+0x38ae>         add    (%eax),%al
0x77d656ab  <+0x38b0>         je     0x77d656c4
<ntdll!RtlpSetUserPreferredUILanguages+14537>
0x77d656ad  <+0x38b2>         mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x77d656b0  <+0x38b5>         movb   $0x1,0x77d7f0a5
0x77d656b7  <+0x38bc>         mov    %eax,0x77d7f0a0
0x77d656bc  <+0x38c1>         int3
0x77d656bd  <+0x38c2>         movb   $0x0,0x77d7f0a5
```

The function that runs in thread

```
uintptr_t __stdcall threadFunction(void* labelPtr)
{

    for(std::list<std::wstring>::iterator i = discLetters.begin(); i != discLetters.end(); ++i)
    {
        findAllFilesInDirectory((*i).c_str(), filesData, (QLabel*)labelPtr);
    }
    Serializer<std::list<FileInfo>> xmlFile("D:\\res.xml");
    xmlFile.serialize(filesData);
}
```

And the thread creation

```
threadHandle = _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &threadFunction, (void*)(ui->currentDirectoryLabel), NULL, NULL);
```

I'm forced to use WinAPI for threading. Can anyone help?

Comment: Non-void pointers are implicitly convertible to void pointers with compatible const-volatile qualifiers. Your cast to `void` in `(void*)(ui->currentDirectoryLabel)` is unnecessary. Also using C style casts is a really bad idea. Use the C++ cast operators like `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast` instead.

Comment: Why are you forced for winapi? That is suboptimal in a Qt application. Either way, can you show your qt gui code which contains QLabel? Are you also forced for non-c++11, like range based for loop, or at least auto? Also, QT is Quick Time. "Qt" is Q toolkit as per tag wiki.

Comment: "For threading should be used platform-dependend API. For UI might be used winAPI, Qt, MFC etc." that is said in my task. I can use c++11 and I know about it possibilities.
`class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
...
 QLabel *currentDirectoryLabel;
...
};
`
If that is what you've asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To change QLabel text I pass pointer to it as a parameter to function that runs in thread.

This is the problem. You may not directly manipulate QWidgets from any thread other than the main thread (the thread that called `QApplication::exec()`).

Per the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/threads-qobject.html):

> the GUI classes, notably QWidget and all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the main thread.

The ideal solution would be to re-work your program so that your worker threads are QThreads and use Qt's signals-and-slots mechanism to handle the inter-thread communication and synchronization automatically.

If you cannot use QThreads, you will have to set up your own inter-thread communication. One way would be with a shared queue protected by a mutex. The worker thread(s) would push items into it, and the GUI thread would poll it occasionally.